# Invalid binary with xcode 8, Asks to add description in Info.plist

Tags: iphone, app-store-connect, ios10, xcode8, info.plist

I Was able to submit my app with Xcode 7 with no error and with not any specific description required in info.plist

But now with Xcode 8, iTunes rejected binary saying that invalid binary and gives error message like:

**"This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain an NSCameraUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data."**

Answer (score 0):

It seems apple has changed some privacy validation for submitting an app to app store.

I found the solution from the error only.
I added **NSCameraUsageDescription** in my info.plist with valid text(attachment) and it worked for me.

There are also some other cases when you will get an invalid binary error for other keys like **NSCalendarsUsageDescription**, **NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription**. The Same solution will work for all such error with valid text for all.[image]